# How to enforce a hard limit on cloud cost?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, monitoring, cost-management

On Amazon AWS, is there a sample set of settings/scripts to enforce a hard limit on cloud cost (storage, compute, networking, ...) such that once a threshold has been
reached, all services are paused or killed.

The Ronin service for monitoring/alerting (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/publicsector/announcing-research-computing-ronin-aws/) seems rather expensive, and appears not to offer this out of the box.

Comment: No, AWS will happily accept your money. You can set up all kinds of alerting and forecasting and warnings and so called budgets but nothing will stop your account from incurring further costs.

Comment: "Stopping services" sounds easy, but is not really possible. Just consider a database or S3 bucket with data in it. The only way to not get billed for a S3 bucket with data in it, is to delete it. So that is definitely not what 99% of users ever would want. That's why it does not make sense to build a feature like this. That said it should be possible to write a tool yourself that would do something like this. Or use a tool like [aws nuke](https://github.com/rebuy-de/aws-nuke).

Comment: In scenarios where the cloud only ever has redundant copies and is used for research experiments rather than for prodution use this does make sense; thanks for the link to AWS Nuke!